# Getting fields of a class from Element

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, element

I have created a custom annotation and used that in a class as follows:

```
@Reportable
public class CustomerModel extends BaseModel {
    public String CustomerName;
    public int orderCount;
}
```

In annotation processor I have all elements that have been annotated with `@Reportable` using the following code:

```
 Set<? extends javax.lang.model.element.Element> elements = 
roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Reportable.class);
```

How can I get fields of that classes? I want to list all properties of `CustomerModel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given one `element` of your `elements` set you can use:

```
List<VariableElement> fields = ElementFilter.fieldsIn(element.getEnclosedElements());
```